# Not able to access nginx from outside world

Tags: nginx, ansible, ubuntu-14.04

Not able to access nginx from outside the server

I have used ansible role written by me to download nginx on linux machines. But i'm not bale to access that nginx service outside of the server (the one on which it is installed)

https://github.com/kishanagarwal/ansible_poc/tree/master/roles/nginx

You can access the code from above url

I am able to get a welcome page of nginx service running on Centos machines, but can't get anything when i tried to access ip address of machine running on ubuntu 14.04 and having nginx installed on it.

Comment: Are you sure nginx is running on the Ubuntu server? Log in and check that it's enable and running

Comment: Have you verified that nginx is *running*? Have you verified that it is listening on the expected port (using e.g. `netstat` or `ss`)?

Comment: Have you verified whether or not the firewall is open on the appropriate port?

Answer (score 0):

Its simply means nginx port is not opened. 
steps to follows:

1. login to your machine which is trying to access nginx.
   if it is windows ,open  DOS prompt OR if it is linux, open terminal. 
   run following command :
   **telnet**

Based on output , if port is not open, you can refer following guide to open port:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/

Comment: I have nginx in such a way to run on port 8080 and firewall rules are open for ubuntu-machine accordingly. When i tried to do a telnet from ansible-control machine then it seems working.

Comment: Try to add host entry in /etc/hosts on Ubuntu. its strange because if you able to telnet, then it must serve pages.